# Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type

Tags: c#, c#-10.0

Using C# 10 I have the interface:

```cs
public interface IPluralRuleProvider {
    Boolean TryGetRule(CultureInfo culture, out PluralizationRuleDelegate rule);
}
```

In a class I am implementing the method and I have:

```cs
Rules = new Dictionary<String, PluralizationRuleDelegate>();

Boolean IPluralRuleProvider.TryGetRule(CultureInfo culture, out PluralizationRuleDelegate rule)
{
    rule = null;

    if (Rules.TryGetValue(culture.Name, out rule))
        return true;    

    if (culture.Parent != null && Rules.TryGetValue(culture.Parent.Name, out rule))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

I am getting the warnings:

> Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type
> Possible null reference assignment

I have been trying different versions but I always get some kind of warning.

Can I change something to avoid this?

Comment: I don't like these `if(condition) return true; else return false;`. You can return the result of the condition directly as it yields the very value you want to return: `return condition;`. Since C# uses short circuit evaluation, we can write:
`return Rules.TryGetValue(culture.Name, out rule) || culture.Parent != null && Rules.TryGetValue(culture.Parent.Name, out rule);`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I think your example is less readable than the OP's - not-least because it relies upon the reader knowing the correct operator precedence for `&&` and `||`... which I keep on forgetting.

Comment: @Dai. You can easily add braces. At least the second if and the 2 returns could be converted to a single return. This keeps the readability.

Comment: This is off topic, but the two "return" styles are for different design considerations. The example above clearly communicates that the default is always to return false, unless some other condition(s) applies. Bundling everything into a single return statement loses that clarification. Whether or not that matters depends on outside factors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I assume when `TryGetRule` returns `false` that the `out rule` parameter will be assigned to `null`.

  - ...in that case you need to add two annotations to `out PluralizationRuleDelegate rule`:

    1. `PluralizationRuleDelegate?` - i.e. "`rule` *can* be `null`".
    2. `[NotNullWhen(true)]` - i.e. "Even though we've declared `rule` as maybe-`null`, we pinky-swear promise that when this method returns `true` that the `out rule` parameter *will not* be `null`.

       - Note that the C# compiler does not (and *cannot*, I think?) exhaustively prove your `[NotNullWhen(true)]` postcondition - so be sure to double-check your logic - consider adding  `&& rule != null` checks to every this.Rules.TryGetValue` call-site too.

Anyway, change your `interface` to this:

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

public interface IPluralRuleProvider {
  Boolean TryGetRule(CultureInfo culture, [NotNullWhen(true)] out PluralizationRuleDelegate? rule);
}
```

and implementation:

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

Boolean IPluralRuleProvider.TryGetRule(CultureInfo culture, [NotNullWhen(true)] out PluralizationRuleDelegate? rule) {

  if (this.Rules.TryGetValue(culture.Name, out rule))
    return true;

  if (culture.Parent != null && this.Rules.TryGetValue(culture.Parent.Name, out rule))
    return true;

  return false;
}
```